# "Access denied" c program on vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

so, i tried to write a c program on vscode and this is the output that i received.

````
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Lily\Documents\vscode prg\" && gcc rect.c -o rect && "c:\Users\Lily\Documents\vscode prg\"rect
rect.c: In function 'main':
rect.c:21:12: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
     return 0;
            ^
rect.c:2:6: note: declared here
 void main()
      ^~~~
Access is denied.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.778 seconds```
````

Comment: Standard defines how `main()` should be defined (as `int main(int argc, char **argv);` or `int main(void)`, but not `void main()`, so you should change your `main` declaration to one of these above.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has minor type errors, for example `main` function should return an integer, so the return type should be `int`, not `void`. You should declare your `main` function in either or these ways:

```c
int main()
```

```c
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

Back to your "Access denied" problem, mostly it's an antivirus issue. I used to have such problems in C. I use mcafee antivirus and whenever I compiled a program it showed "Access is denied" and then mcafee used to show a notification saying "We just removed a virus". My suspicion grew and I went to quarantine items in mcafee and I found my executable file. Apparently antivirus sometimes confuse C programs for a virus. You can either turn off your antivirus (turn off realtime scanner in case of mcafee) or tell your antivirus to not check for viruses in your project folder.

Let me know if I made a mistake, have a great day!

Comment: i did so but it still wont compile it/takes a very long time to load the output. I never received an output unless it is just a simple printf statement.

Comment: I believe you are using Code Runner to run your code. Code Runner only displays print statements, it will not work if your program asks for user input. To overcome that, go to File > Preferences > Settings. Then click on extensions, then scroll down to "Run Code configurations". There, scroll down till you get the "Run in Terminal" option. Check it and reload vscode. Then your programs will run in terminal and would work perfectly fine. Let me know if you are having problems, happy coding!